# SQL: Selecting existence of an entry in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to select whether or not an entry exists in another table. Here's a simple example:

Two tables:

```
Student
ID   Major
1    CS
2    CS
3    CS
4    CS

Student_Teacher 
SID  TID 
1    A 
1    B 
1    C 
3    B 
3    D
```

The first table has a list of student IDs (key = Student ID)
The 2nd table has a list of student -> teachers (key = Student ID, Teacher ID combination).

I would like to select ALL students (1,2,3,4; one in each row) and a flag for whether or not they have a teacher.

```
SELECTED:
ID   Flag
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
```

I know this is possible to do using group by:

```
select Student.ID, count(Student_Teacher.TID)
from Student left join Student_Teacher 
group by Student.ID
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try joining to a derived table that contains the distinct student id values of the second table:

```
SELECT ID, IF(ST.SID IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS FLAG
FROM Student AS S
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT SID
   FROM Student_Teacher
) AS ST ON S.ID = ST.SID
```

Comment: OP asked for a simpler query, this seems less simple to me. I also guess that this a bit slower because you use a derived table.

Comment: @Kontsnor It is less simple indeed. The OP can inform us how the query compares to his when actual data are used.

Comment: Great solution, testing it now.

Comment: The inner select actually turned out to be faster for me. I am selecting 25+ columns at times and having to group by all 25 columns except 1 is messy and a little slower too.

Comment: @Rimoun Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.